# UILocalNotification when app is closed

Tags: objective-c

Using the  `UILocalNotification`  when the app is open, this function in the app delegate is fired :

```
 - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
{
```

but when the app is close and not in the background, it starts the app when i hit the notification massage, but it doesnt fire this method.

i need to fire it because she is the one who take me to another scene-that i need to present when someone get the notification.

it works only when she is on background .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to implement `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`. The notification will be one of the options.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application 
  didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    UILocalNotification *notification = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];
    if (notification) {
        // handle your notification here.
    }
}
```

Comment: actually it doesn't work when the app is closed. i havae tried to put there         [director_ pushScene: [mainScene scene]];   to replace a scene and it didnt worked .

Comment: If all of your (cocos2d) setup is made in an other method (`application:didFinishLaunching:`), then that won't be executed. I recommend moving all the required launch setup into a separate method and calling it from both `didDinishLaunching:` methods. I hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: i understood,but why it won't be execute ? so whats to different if i put all setups in another method and then call it from didFinishLaunching ?

Comment: exactly where you said in didFinishLaunching. so what should i do ?

Comment: ok i got it, its works now, i just had 2 functions of the same name didfinishlaunching.  thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5):

From the specs:

```
If the action button is tapped (on a device running iOS), the system 
launches the application and the application calls its delegate’s    
application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method (if implemented); it passes 
in the notification payload (for remote notifications) or the local-notification 
object (for local notifications).
```

In other words, `application:didReceiveLocalNotification` is only for when, as you've found, the app is running.

If the app is LAUNCHED due to a local (or for that matter remote) notification, the goods from the notification are passed into the `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method, and that's where you catch that.